# In JavaFX, how to disable the list from auto fill text box if the entered value is not present in the list?

Tags: javafx

I'm using the javafx-autocomplete-field-1.0 jar to add an auto fill textbox in my FXML page. I need to disable the list that drops down when there is no matching text in the list. If anybody has used this jar and achieved the same, kindly share the thoughts.

Comment: Do you mean that the drop down list should be hidden when empty, because it should be doing that already ?

Comment: No drop down list has values. When I start entering the text, if the drop down does not contain values that starts with the text entered, it should hide the list. Instead it is showing an empty list (like a line) below the text field.

Comment: try this version: https://bitbucket.org/jugen/autofilltextbox/downloads